# Change I-beam cursor to only 1px like on Windows

Tags: windows, xorg, cursor, mir, wayland

How to change the current 3 px wide I-beam (select-text) cursor to only 1 px wide like on Windows.

I am using Unity as my DE fro Ubuntu 15, if that helps.

As far as I know Chrome OS and Chromium OS does have this 1 px wide I-beam cursor.

http://www.omgchrome.com/new-cursors-coming-to-chrome-os/

So, why it is not in Ubuntu too? It's much easier to select and copy/paste stuff with this "sharp" 1px wide cursor , instead of trying to aim between single quotes or strings like "lll" using 3px wide cursor that is wider than a character you want to cut or paste.

[This is not possible on Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOtCw.gif)